# Slow Motion Comedic Action Effect

Tags: reverb, slow, motion, sfx

This is a "what is that" sort of question, and also, a "why can't I find an example of it" question.

In some older martial arts movies, and goofy action sequences, the action will slow down as some flies through the air, or does something incredible and instead of music or a slow-mo sound, there is this really reverb-y "tick tick tick tick".  I don't think it's used seriously any more.

So questions are:
-Can you give an example, cause I sure can't find one.
-Does it have a name?
-How is/was it first made?

Thank ya!

Comment: Do you have a clip, or anything we could see/hear?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KW2CVjCb6iU 0:52 this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's one at the end of this clip yes?

[youtube]7eYESAPx0n0[/youtube]

To me it sounds like the reversed delay of a Kendo stick smack.

Take your sound.  Reverse it.  Record the delay to another track.  Flip the original back and line it up with the first hit of the delay.

I tried it to see if I could do it:

[soundcloud]g-a-harry/kung-fu-slo-mo-test-2[/soundcloud]

The sound is an 8-bit snare hit, pitched up about an octave and a half.  Added some filtered pink to get in the tape degredation. Doesn't *quite* work (the impact is kinda weak), but it's on the right track.

Comment: ah!! yeah, that's it!!  usually goes on waaaaay longer than that :)  nice find, thank you.

Comment: @VCProd, Wow, that is sooo the wrong sound to have used.  I'll try it again later.  If you're planning on actually making this you should d/l Massey's tape emulator and run it through that.  I'm assuming it was made using multi-tap tape delay, which would explain the gross amount of noise on it.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean but generally in the old kung-fu flicks any slow-down moments of intense fighting action were accompanied by a heavy touch of reverb.

From around 3min20 in this clip:

[youtube]LYBFDQJPPwQ[/youtube]

And some good examples in this clip:

[youtube]wA5XAafIfiQ[/youtube]

Comment: @Colin, I love the scoring in those old flicks.  